I'm looking for a manhwa where humans become small and with that they gain powers
I don't remember many details, but I remember there is a chapter where they were on a cable car and out of nowhere it explodes.

Welcome to the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works.  This question contains very little information, which might make ID impossible. Please edit in any details, including things like when you read this, when think the manga might have been published, cover images etc.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

I think you're thanking of the movie Ant-Man.

I think this is microHunter (I know it as "3 cm Hunter").
It has been some time since I read this, and I can not remember the scene with
the cable car, but everyone becomes tiny, gets a special power and game-like stats and quests.
The MC is out buying snacks for his sister when this happens, and he gets a quest to "Find the princess" and some kind of shield/barrier power.
